# keep the group if the corrosponding row meet certain criteria Python

Tags: python, group-by

This is my original dataframe

[image]

For original dataset, each company has the action of 'Sell', 'Not Sell', or both'Sell' and 'Not sell'. I want to keep the company that has both 'Sell' and ;Not Sell', and delete the company that has only one action.

I am thinking to first group it by Date and Company, then for each group, I only keep the company that has two action.
I used the below code

```
sell=['Sell','Not Sell']
df['Action'].str.contains(sell).groupby([df['Date'],df['Company']]).transform('any')
```

But it returns 'unhashable type: 'list''

Comment: `df[df.Action.str.contains("Sell")]`

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. You're using Pandas, right? Please [edit] and add the tag for it. Next, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Copy the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). It also helps to provide the code to create `df` so that we don't have to infer (like, if you're reading the data from this Excel file, then I guess you're using ffill). For more tips, see [ask].